# What does "fill-in-the-blank" mean in the following context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> She is a fill-in-the-blank at the radio station.

Does it mean that she does anything she is asked to do?

Comment: I don't think this is an established usage, so the question is too localised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context I would take that to mean something along the lines of:

> She's a jack of all trades at the radio station, capable of doing any number of roles.

Comment: That's somewhat the opposite of my interpretation, which is that the reference is to someone who fills in when a 'warm body' (an unskilled person) is needed.

Comment: @jwpat7: Interesting, quite possibly a 'regional' thing. I suppose "fill-in-the-blank" could also imply that the inference should be obvious, perhaps from other context, but given a lack of that context, my interpretation comes from "fill-in-the-blank" usually meaning that you can put anything you want in the blank spot.

Comment: +1 to @jwpat7.  If she were valued for her skills, she'd be given a nicer description.  As it is, that description implies to me that she is not valued and given roles only when they have nobody else to fill them at that time.

Comment: @itsbruce: Why not offer your version as a different answer then, instead of +1'ing a comment and downvoting the only answer available? My interpretation is _different_, not _wrong_ (I think). I suspect that FumbleFingers was correct and one's interpretation depends on where one is from, but there's nothing wrong with having an alternative answer, even long after the question has been asked. That way, people can upvote the answer they feel is right and over time, the "more common" one will win out.